# Add an object value as key to the interface or state

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

I have the following mainObject which contains key and value pairs and I would like to use this object's value as a key to an interface or state. The following I provided an example of an interface.

```
//Main Object
export const mainObject = {
  NAME:'name',
  AGE:'age'
}
```

Now I want main object values as a key to an interface

```
interface sample {
    'name':string //i want to achieve like this
}
//modifying the below
import mainObject from '';
interface sample {
    mainObject.NAME:string  //will give error, need to modify this
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that **if** `mainObject` is declared as a runtime constant (not just the `mainObject` binding, but the object it contains), via `as const`:

```typescript
export const mainObject = {
    NAME: "name",
    AGE: "age",
} as const;
//^^^^^^^^
```

Then you can get the type of that object via `typeof`:

```typescript
type MainObjectType = typeof mainObject;
```

Then you can use that type to create a mapped type for `Sample`:

```typescript
type Sample = {
    [key in MainObjectType[keyof MainObjectType]]: string;
};
```

With your current definition of `mainObject`, that would make this code valid:

```typescript
const x: Sample = {
    name: "something",
    age: "something else",
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYEMCWyDyARgFbALwC8cA3gFBwNwByAggLICiAXHAETJYMwXgBp6jFgHFufLAHNhYgL5wsqRCnQBuWrRgBPMMDhtcBEmRgAVQ8aoGjEAGZxseIqXI6HxgMqCwABs7GnEGAG0Aa2B9ODwTMw9LGyMomOcE9wtyFOAAXTyedCg8OR0lHVokNHgQHn8MIJC6RjgBIR5eVAghGAALUtEw1QVO7t6B5Dk4YEDURVoKoA)

If you changed the properties in `mainObject`, the types would change, and `x` would need to be updated to have the new properties. For example, if we added `EXAMPLE: "example",` to `mainObject` but didn't update `x` above, we'd get an error that `x` was missing the `example` property — [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wLYEMCWyDyARgFbALwC8cA3gFBwNwByAggLICiAXHAETJYMwXgBp6jFgHFufLAHNhYxnA4ANdgAUAMjN6hBYADaLaAXzhZUiFOgDctWjACeYYHDa4CJMjAAqLtypnVwgAMzhsPCJScntgtwBlA2M4KjplAG0Aa2AnODx3T2iff1ds3LDCqO9yUuAAXXqedCg8OXtTe1okNHgQHiSMI0CaOAB6MbgAHgpZuA0oCFdYPIByfSHjVfyrDBxUVDa4UMWMOHiAOivxBgEhHl5UCCEYAAs20RuLBQenl-fkHI4MBDKgTJ0gA).